# Migrate Ejabberd from Mnesia Database to SQLite on Debian 9 Stretch

Tags: database, sqlite, raspberry-pi, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm new to this but seeing this as my last hope I give it a shot.
I just managed to install and configure ejabberd (Debian-backport-package) on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian (Debian 9).

As I'm still new to coding, Linux and so on, please correct me if I'm wrong but I understood using the default mnesia database is limited and one should use MySQL, SQLite, MariaDB etc?!...
I just want to use ejabberd for private messaging with friends and family, sharing files and audio-messages... 
1. Is it really necessary to move to another database?
2. I've sqlite3 running for baikal and seafile already and with the limited ressources of a Raspberry Pi 2 I think SqLite should be my choice for ejabberd aswell, right?
3. How do I set up a new database in SQLite (I already tried figuring it out via the Documentation about how to migrate to MySQL and by searching the internet, but didn't really understood something...) and 
4. how would I tell ejabberd incl. Modules (global would be enough) to use the new SQlite database?

I don't need to migrate the existing database to sqlite, just creating a new one and bind ejabberd to it would be perfect!

I guess this isnt like a big deal at all for somebody reading this and would be very thankful if I get some advice.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I understood using the default mnesia database is limited and one
>   should use MySQL, SQLite, MariaDB etc?!...

That's true for a medium or large server, as mnesia wouldn't be capable of handling a large userbase. In such case, a good PostgreSQL or other SQL database is preferable.

> I just want to use ejabberd for private messaging with friends and
>   family, 1. Is it really necessary to move to another database?

Only a few hundred of accounts registered and used simultaneously, for typical user chat (not bots)...? Then the internal mnesia is just enough.

Comment: thats just what i wanted to hear - thank you very much